# How to handle asynchronous behaviour of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() in Redux and store on Redux state the position of the user?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-thunk

How to handle asynchronous behaviour of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() in Redux and store on Redux state the position of the user ?

I started using Redux recently. I want to store the user coordinates on Redux state so I don't have to call it on every pages of my app. I am using redux-thunk, which is working fine when I use it to handle asynchronous behaviour fetching data from an API. But it is not working as expected when I want to handle asynchronous behaviour from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition method.

```
// Action file

export function getUserLocation() {
    return dispatch => {
        const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            console.log('position.coords', position.coords); // Getting the expected object
            dispatch({
                type: GET_USER_LOCATION,
                payload: position
            });
        });
    };
}


// Reducer file

import { GET_USER_LOCATION } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

function userLocationReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USER_LOCATION:
            console.log('action.payload', action.payload); // Getting the expected object
            return { ...action.payload };
    }
    return state;
}

export default userLocationReducer;


// View file

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserLocation(); // Calling as expected
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props.userLocation) // Always an empty object...
}
```

I expected this.props.userLocation to be NOT an empty object when calling it in the render method of my view component but it is always empty.

I am sure that this.props.userLocation is plugged correctly through the mapStateToProps method (I tried passing a random object without those asynchronous methods from the action file and I am getting it on the view). I guess my problem is due to the asynchronous behaviour of getCurrentPosition() and I can not figure out how to dispatch it once I have gotten the user position and not before.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or any working example, i can't see anything wrong here

Comment: if you don't know, `this.props.userLocation` will be empty on initial render, it will update when the asynchronous action complete. and rerender the component with updated value.

Comment: you would have to have a default geolocation or NULL untill user location is loaded AND THEN triggerc re-render when geolocation is loaded